# Datatable Error Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined

Tags: php, javascript, datatables

Estoy mostrando los datos desde mi Base de Datos en una tabla mediante **javascript**  los datos se muestran correctamente, pero no se están mostrando las opciones de **DataTable**. En la consola del navegador me arroja este error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined
at HTMLTableCellElement.<anonymous> (datatables.js:1184)
at Function.each (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
at r.fn.init.each (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (datatables.js:1181)
at Function.each (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
at r.fn.init.each (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
at r.fn.init.DataTable [as dataTable] (datatables.js:881)
at r.fn.init.$.fn.DataTable (datatables.js:15082)
at Object.success (pagos_tipos.js:14)
at i (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
```

Los datos son mostrados mediante Javascript

```
 $.post(url+"C_Pagos_Tipos/getPagos",
 function(data){

 var obj = JSON.parse(data);
 $.each(obj, function(i, item){
 $("#tblPagos").append(
  '<tr>'+
  '<td>'+item.id+'</td>'+
  '<td>'+item.tipo_pago+'</td>'+
  '<td><a href="#" title="Editar" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditar" onClick="selPagos(\''+item.id+'\',\''+item.tipo_pago+'\');"><i style="color:#555;" ></i> Editar</a></td>'+
  '</tr>'
);
});
$("#tblPagos").DataTable({

'paging': true,
'info': true,
'filter': true

});
});
```

[image: **introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí**]

Editado: agregue el html

```
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped" id="tblPagos">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#Código</th>
              <th>Nombre</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          </tbody>
        </table>

      </div>
```

Al final del HTML

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
 </script>

 <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/datatables/datatables.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/datatables/datatables.js"></script>

 <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/pagos_tipos.js"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: ¿Cómo tiene su HTML ?

Comment: Lo acabo de Editar

Comment: Cuántas columnas retorna su ruta `getPagos`

Comment: Dos, el otro es el botón para editar

Comment: id, y tipo_pago

Comment: Agregue un `th` vacío al final después del `th` nombre

Comment: Gracias, me funciono perfecto, pero, porque sucede eso?(podrías agregarlo como respuesta para seleccionarla porfavor?)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Es un error bastante común. Ya que la condición para un `DataTable` es que el número de columnas en el `thead` sea igual al del `tbody`, tiene sólo dos en el `thead` pero añade un botón adicional al `tbody`  por tanto excede en uno las columnas, entonces su error se puede solucionar simplemente añadiendo una `th` vacío al final para igualar la columnas.

Comment: Solo comentario: no es el numero de filas sino el numero de columnas el que debe ser igual